# Can't download 2 files by one click (different urls)

Tags: javascript, url, download, window

I have button and two checkboxes. If two checkboxes are checked, I have to call 2 different urls for files downloading. One url is calling well, but second blocking by browser.

```
window.open('http://example.com/getFirstFile', '_blank');
window.open('http://example.com/getSecondFile', '_blank');
```

Also I've tried to use

```
window.location = 'http://example.com/getFirstFile';
window.location = 'http://example.com/getSecondFile';
```

and with defer

```
window.location = 'http://example.com/getFirstFile';

setTimeout(function() {
   window.location = 'http://example.com/getSecondFile';
}, 1000);
```

Nothing from that doesn't work.

How could I call two links for files download?

Comment: "but second blocking by browser". What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Some actions in browsers require user action to be initiated first.  For example if you used a media control, you can't action a play request unless a click handler was first instantiated.

Opening windows is most likely one of these events too, so unless the user actions another click, window.open gets blocked.

You can even see this happen from the console,  try -> `window.open('http://www.microsoft.com', '_blank');window.open('http://www.google.co.uk', '_blank');` you will notice only microsoft's website will open.

But if you do them as two separate console requests, they will both open.

The obvious reason for this is to stop malicious websites from spamming your browser.

What's doing the blocking here is the popup blocker, so there is options to override this.  But again it's the user who has to allow this to happen.   So in Chrome you should see a popup blocker icon appear, you should be able to select always allow, and then you will be able to open multiple windows without another user interaction been required.